# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT Google places

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-places-api

I want to check hospitals near me, but I get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error. The fact is that the key is new and didn`t use before. What can be the problem?

```
@app.route('/hospitals', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hospitals():
    g = geocoder.ip('me')
    lt_lg = g.latlng

lt = lt_lg[0]
lg = lt_lg[1]

API_KEY = 'mykey'

google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    lat_lng ={'lat': lt, 'lng': lg},
    radius = 5000,
    types =[types.TYPE_HOSPITAL])

if query_result.has_attributions:
    print (query_result.html_attributions)


for place in query_result.places:
    print("Latitude", place.geo_location['lat'])
    print("Longitude", place.geo_location['lng'])
    return render_template('hospitals.html', places=query_result.places)
```

Comment: Did you enable billing account?

Comment: @xomena, no, I thought that I have a limit to use it without billing

Comment: Without billing you have 1 request per day.

Comment: @xomena I didn’t know about this. Now I get ‘REQUEST_DENIED’ error. I used key only on localhost. What can be the problem?